# xml parsing in objective c accessing attributes

Tags: objective-c, xml, parsing

I am trying to parse a xml file but I couldn't be able to retrive all objects in it.

My xml is

```
<exam>
<question s="1" a="2" m="1"  x="1">
    <q>question</q>
    <o p="">question</o>
    <o p="">question</o>
    <o p="">question</o>
    <o p="">question</o>

</question>
<question s="2" a="1,3,5" m="3" p="1.2.jpg" x="1">
    <q>question</q>
    <o p="">question</o>
    <o p="">question</o>
    <o p="">question</o>
    <o p="">question</o>
    <o p="">question</o>
    <o p="">question</o>
</question>
</exam>
```

How can I retrieve all data such as " s="2" " and "<.o p=>question<./o>"

Comment: Perhaps start by [reading the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLParser_Class/Reference/Reference.html)? Believe me, it's *super useful.*

Comment: Your XML is valid, so the problem is in the Objective-C code, post it please.

Comment: Hello! Could you put the answer in an answer instead of putting it within the question body! Could you also remove the "solved" from the title! For more information see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/172501/community-edit-request-solved-fixed-answered. Thank you for your help on keeping the site as consistent and clean as possible!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your help.  Here is the solution I found with a friend's help (sorry for the poorly chosen variable names):

```
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
    currentElement = elementName;
    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"item"])
    {
        qes = [[Qes alloc] init];
        qes.s= [attributeDict objectForKey:@"s"];

    }

}

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{
    if([currentElement isEqualToString:@"q"])
        [qes.question appendString:string];
    if([currentElement isEqualToString:@"o"])
    {
        [qes.answers addObject:string];
    }

}

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{
    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"item"])
    {
        [quests addObject:qes];

    }
}
-(void)parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser
{
    for (Qes *s in quests) {
        NSLog(s.question);
        NSLog(@"s-----");
        NSLog(s.s);

        for (NSString *w in s.answers) {
             NSLog(w);

        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `GDataXML`  & Consider `xmlData` will be the XML strings `NSData` representation.

```
GDataXMLDocument *doc = [[GDataXMLDocument alloc] initWithData:xmlData error:&error];

NSArray *dataArray = [doc nodesForXPath:@"//exam/question" error:nil];

  for (GDataXMLElement *element in dataArray) {

        NSArray * question = [element elementsForName:@"s"];

        if (question.count > 0) {
            GDataXMLElement *questionElement = (GDataXMLElement *) [question objectAtIndex:0];
            questionString = [questionElement stringValue];
        }
}
```

See more details [here](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/28567)